# UIBarButtonItem action with parameter

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I had some problem, i need to add an UIBarButtonItem who call a method named "valider"

```
- (void) valider:(NSString*) firstParam
{
    NSLog(@"Logs %@", firstParam);
}
```

and i creat my UIBarButtonItem like this, but i need to pass my first parameter !

```
UIBarButtonItem *buttonValiderAddSerie = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Valider" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(valider:)];
```

I tried this but it doesn't work for me...

```
UIBarButtonItem *buttonValiderAddSerie = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Valider" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered

[buttonValidAddSerie addTarget:self action:@selector(valider:) firstParam:@"first"];
```

Thank's for reading,

Tommy

Answer (score 1):

`UIButtonBarItem`s actions signature look like

```
- (void)didTapButtonBarItem:(id)sender;
```

The `sender` parameter is a pointer to the button currently pressed.

You have to store your `first` parameter elsewhere in your class, then retrieve it when you tap on `buttonValidAddSerie`.

Comment: ok so i had to create a class extend to UIButton then do something like (MyButton) sender...

Comment: You could extend `UIButtonBarItem`, yes. Just add to it a single member like `(NSString *)first`, add it as a `@property`, then just after creating your ButtonBarItem-subclass, set its `first` to whatever you want. Just don't forget to cast your `sender` back to your subclass on `didTapBarButtonItem`, like that: `NSString *first = [(MYBarButtonItemSubclass *)sender first]`.